# gzipping for faster page loading speed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, gzip

I want to gzip our website which is www.urbanlocker.co.uk to make the page loading faster. I have no idea if it is apache web server, lingx or how to find out which one it is. By the way I have access to filezilla to upload/download files but not to the hosting company. I am copying pasting these codes beşow to enable gzipping and upload the .htaccess file to the root folder but nothing has worked. Does anyone know where I am doing wrong?

This one is recommended for Apache:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

another one:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

and this one is recommended for nginx:

```
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml           application/xml+rss text/javascript;

# Disable for IE < 6 because there are some known problems
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";

# Add a vary header for downstream proxies to avoid sending cached gzipped files to IE6
gzip_vary on;
```

Please let me know if you need any further information. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: From the HTTP headers, it is IIS / ASP.NET and it is already gzip'd.

Comment: Builtwith is your friend: http://builtwith.com/?q=www.urbanlocker.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://builtwith.com your server is IIS and it is already gzipping content.

Strongly recommend you know what type of server you are using before you start trying to optimize.

To check headers and gzip, you can use a tool like http://redbot.org/

Comment: But when I check this website http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/ and type www.urbanlocker.co.uk it shows my website as not compressed. That confused me.

Comment: You may have a caching issues or incorrect setup. I get different results for http://urbanlocker.co.uk/ vs. http://www.urbanlocker.co.uk/. I would speak with your host because this should not occur.  If caching is used, then a Vary: Accept-Encoding header should be used to cache both non and gzipped versions.

Answer (score 0):

Using Curl on the command-line will return all headers from the responding server. This information often includes a "Server" header which reveals the type of application server that is handling the request.

```
$ curl -I www.urbanlocker.co.uk
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 19834
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Mon, 09 Jun 2014 11:40:54 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "addd6abd783cf1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
Date: Mon, 09 Jun 2014 17:00:18 GMT
```

Comment: thank you this also works but I chose the other answer cus it gives more info